# Template parameter type deduction

Tags: c++, templates

I'm fiddling around with template meta-programming again and trying to get a better understanding of it.  I've created the following trivial template meta-function.

```
template<typename T, T Value>
struct is_positive
{
    static const bool value = (Value >= 0);
}

const bool is_positive_test_1 = is_positive<int32_t, 3>::value;  //true
const bool is_positive_test_2 = is_positive<int32_t, 0>::value;  //true
const bool is_positive_test_3 = is_positive<int32_t, -1>::value; //false
```

Everything works fine, as expected, but I want to know if there is a way that I can eliminate the need to specify the type of the `Value` parameter, so the calling convention would instead be:

```
is_positive<1>::value
```

Thank you in advance. :)

**EDIT**

I would like this to not *just* work for `int32_t`, but also `float32_t` and any other numeric type.  For example, I want `is_positive<3.141f>::value` to be valid without needing to specialize the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only function template parameters can be deduced, not class template parameters.  In C++03 you can't have compile time functions, but in C++11 you can using `constexpr`:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_positive(T val) {
    return val >= 0;
}
```

And just to show that it is evaluated at compile time, the following will compile:

```
template<bool V>
struct compile_time_tester
{};

int main() {
    compile_time_tester<is_positive(3.14)> foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using VS2013's compiler which doesn't yet support `constexpr`. :(

Answer (score 1):

One good trick is to give the first argument a default value in case not any is given for it:

```
template<typename T=int32_t, T Value>
```

So that you have:

```
template<typename T=int32_t, T Value>
struct is_positive
{
    static const bool value = (Value >= 0);
}

const bool is_positive_test_1 = is_positive<3>::value;  //true
const bool is_positive_test_2 = is_positive<0>::value;  //true
const bool is_positive_test_3 = is_positive<-1>::value; //false
```

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

UPDATE:

It seems that you are additionally searching for an automatic way of variable type decision. My mind goes to dynamic typing (meaning that the type of the argument is recognized at runtime and not on compile-time).Many languages use dynamic typing (such as `PHP` and Python) but `C++` is a static typing language, meaning that you have to declare the type of your variable (for example `int i = 0;`) and this type will be set for the variable at compile time. Therefore, what you are asking for can not be done automatically in `C++`.

Comment: Works, but I made an edit to my original post that better explains what I'm trying to do. :)